# What is the reason for the obscure error in dir /al /s in command to report junctions -> file not found?

Tags: windows, cmd, filesystems, junction

We have some code in C#:

```cs
RunProcessAndWaitForExit("cmd.exe", $"/C dir {pstrDriveLetter}:\\ /al /s > {pstrDriveLetter}:\\junctions.log");
```

In more simple terms its:

```
dir C:\ /al /s > D:\junctions.log
```

It is failing in *some* cases with:

```
2022-05-22 08:08:52 INFORMATION "Exception generated when running junction logger: cmd.exe finished with exit code = 1: Error: ERR: File Not Found
 Out:
```

I'm really confused as what this could be:

I don't think it's doing a redirection to a file that doesn't exist as that fails with:

```
C:\repos\therepo [fix-dj-delete-snapshots ≡]> cmd.exe /c dir C:\ /al /s > B:\test.log
Out-File: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'B' does not exist.
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: FYI, there is not just one argument to `cmd.exe`, the first argument is `/C`, and the second argument is `"Dir {pstrDriveLetter}:\ /A:L /S 1> {pstrDriveLetter}:\\junctions.log"`; or in the case of doublequoted paths, `"Dir "P:\ath To\Source-Directory" /A:L /S 1> "P:\ath To\Destination-Directory\file.ext""`. The `/C` or `/K` argument should always be independently double-quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think this just means that it found no junctions!

Comment: Yes, the Windows command __DIR__ exits with `1` which means `cmd.exe` exits with `1` if no matching file system entry can be found. As the C# code results in running `cmd.exe /C dir D:\ /al /s > D:\junctions.log` with two times drive `D:`, the result is most likely absolute correct.

Comment: Your command would still provide output to `junctions.log`, _(due to the lack of a `/B` option with `Dir`)_. If that file isn't being written to, there is simply an issue with the command translated to `cmd.exe`.